# Correct use of for loop, substring, and conversion of hexadecimal ascii code to character?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, substring, ascii

I am trying to create my own java encryption program that encrypts a string: It takes a string and converts each character to its hexadecimal ascii representation. My encryption is to add a random number and random letter on each side of the two numbers that represent the hexadecimal ascii for each character. This will return a 6 character string for each character that is encrypted. E.g. (help -> h -> 68 -> 3+6+g+1+8+f) I am trying to implement using four functions (encryptMessage, encryptCharacter, decryptMessage, decryptCharacter).
I searched the site and could not find any posts that helped me.
Could you possibly help me identify why I can't decrypt my message successfully using the decryptCharacter/decryptMessage methods? I am running just one character through right now and it is not returning the same character that I enter initially.
1. Am I using my for loops correctly in the decryptMessage and decryptCharacter methods? 2. In method decryptCharacter am I correctly converting the ascii hexadecimal representation back into its respective character? If not could someone explain how I could correct my code?

I have my program posted on pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/6QMFYrKD

Any help is appreciated! I am new to java and I am trying to write the program to better understand how to use these methods that are called upon by the main program!

Comment: Don't use pastebin. Post the relevant code here. Only give enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the encryption works (you should be able to verify that manually), then a simplified program to decrypt *(minimal)* is what you should post here, with a call using the encrypted string *(complete)*, and the expected output *(verifiable)*. Also, please use paragraphs in your text. That big block of text is unwieldy.

Comment: Sorry! I will simplify and follow these guidelines in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the `DecryptCharacter` method is not decrypting properly. You are adding the random char and number to each digit of the hexadecimal representation of the character.
so, You should be doing this

```
String hexRep = encryptedCharacter.substring(1, 2) + encryptedCharacter.substring(4, 5)
```

instead of

```
String hexRep = encryptedCharacter.substring(1, 4);
```

Also,

There is a bug in `DecryptMessage` method

The if condition `if (i >= encryptedText.length() - 6) {` wont work because it will always return false till the last 6 chars of the encrypted message,
so, you can try something as below.

```
if (encryptedText.length() > 0 && encryptedText.length() % 6 == 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a great help. I will never use substrings and if statement conditions so poorly again!